# Can I claim a UK or foreign charity donation as tax deductible in Canada?

Tags: canada, united-kingdom, charity, donation, tax-deduction

Can I claim a UK charity donation as tax deductible in Canada?

More generally, are charitable donations to foreign charities tax deductible in Canada?

Answer (score 5):

No in general; at least in Canada the charity must be on the government list: [Canada Revenue](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/chrts-gvng/dnrs/menu-eng.html)

Many international charities do have a Canadian arm like *DOCTORS WITHOUT BORDERS* so you might find your favourite charity on there.

Comment: I have asked a similar question but regarding the U.S.A https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/92051/are-dual-us-canadian-citizens-in-canada-required-to-pay-us-taxes-on-their-donati